# Why I can`t set background color by using setcolor?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that procude random color. I want to take this random color everytime i click on button.I tried to set the color **setBgColor(random_bg_color())**But it gives error like this.**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.** How can i call my random color function and set in hook?

```
import React, {useContext } from 'react';
import {GeneralContext} from "./App"


export default function Theme() {


    function random_bg_color() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120);
        var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120);
        const rgb = 'rgb(' + x + ',' + y + ',' + z + ')';
        return rgb;
      }
      




const {value,value2,value3}=useContext(GeneralContext)
const [text, setText] = value;
const [author,setAuthor] = value2;
const [bgColor,setBgColor]=value3
setBgColor(random_bg_color())







    return (
        <div>
            <p>{bgColor}</p>
            <p>{author}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can't place `setBgColor` at the top level of your component, because that will trigger infinite state update.

Comment: Yes, like Medi hinted. Make button or something `<button onClick={() => setBgColor(random_bg_color())
 } >Click me!</button>`

Comment: @Medi can u show it in snipped? I tried all fractions.I changed their place but it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set it once when the component renders you can use the useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setBgColor(random_bg_color());
},[])
```

The empty array which is the second parameter of the useEffect hook ensures that this code will run when the component mounts.

Comment: useEffect lead to take the rgb once only.When i click twice it doesnt change rgb.

Comment: Well yes, that is the idea so you don't make an endless cycle. If you want to change the color when you click on something you need to create a handler like @jonahe suggested.

Answer (score 1):

create a handler and pass it to the `onClick` of your button

```
const handleClick = ()=>{
  setBgColor(random_bg_color());
}
```